# Service controller class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I  have a windows service  running on a remote machine. I need to control it through a C# web application. Is it possible to use Service controller class to control remote windows service? Is there a better way to doing this?

Answer (score 3):

Use the overload of `ServiceController` that takes two parameters.  The first is the service name and the second is the computer name.

**ServiceController Constructor (String, String)**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ssbk2tf3.aspx

```
public ServiceController(
    string name,
    string machineName
)
```

The active identity will need permissions on the remote machine.  If your application is not running with these permissions but you have credentials for a user with the permissions, you can use impersonation.

**WindowsIdentity.Impersonate Method**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w070t6ka.aspx